# how to choose a greater than date when date is in mmm-dd-yyyy format

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which the date is displayed in mmm-dd-yyyy format, I want to use a greater than in this date ( like date greater than october 2014) , can anyone suggest the sql query for this.

Comment: date in `mmm-dd-yyyy` format ? whats that extra `m` ?

Comment: @abhikchakraborty 'oct-31-2014' perhaps?

Comment: You really should consider storing your dates in mysql native data types for dates like `date,datetime,timestamp`.. you are storing as varchar and you need to use `str_to_date` function to convert it to a real date for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

you can format the date first then sort

```
  select * form table where DATE_FORMAT(date_colomn,'\%e/%c/%Y\')>your_date_here
```

or this one

```
 select * form table where DATE_FORMAT(date_colomn,'%Y-%m-%d')>your_date_here
```